# How can I get if .. else to work?

Tags: string, perl, if-statement

I wrote a Perl program where the user should type in a user name. If they enter `admin`, they should see the message

```
Welcome, admin!
```

Otherwise the console output should be

```
The username is incorrect
```

Here is my code

```perl
use utf8;

print "Username: ";

$username = <STDIN>;

if ( $username eq "admin" ) {
    print "Welcome, admin!";
}
else {
    print "The username is incorrect.";
}
```

But whatever the user inputs the program goes on to the `else` branch.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because you have `admin␊` (`admin` and a line feed). Use `chomp`!

Answer (score 8):

Whenever you are not sure why a comparison fails, make sure you know what's in your variable:

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper $variable;
# print Dumper \@array;
# print Dumper \%hash;
```

like @ikegami suggested, you need to use chomp:

```
chomp $username;
```

[perldoc -f chomp](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)

Answer (score 5):

The empty `<>` operator is usually the best choice for input. It will read data from any files named on the command line, or from the keyboard if there were none

Your `$username = <STDIN>` will read from the keyboard, and if you enter `admin` and the *enter* key it will contain `"admin\n"`. So you need to `chomp` the LF character from the end of the input

You should also `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the start of every Perl program

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

print "Username: ";
my $user_name = <>;
chomp $user_name;

if ( $user_name eq 'admin' ) {
    print "Welcome, admin!\n";
}
else {
    print "The username is incorrect\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I didn't actually know what chomp does.

Comment: @MateașMario a little shortcut to make it a 1 liner is: chomp(my $user_name = <STDIN>);

Answer (score 3):

The comparison never succeed because you don't remove the line feed created by pressing Enter. Use `chomp`!

Comment: If I use chomp I will have to remove the 'Username: ' message and I don't want that.

Comment: @Mateas: That isn't true. Why do you say so?

Comment: @Mateaș: The prompt *output* has nothing to do with the typed *input*

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else already mentioned, you have a line feed and `chomp` will sort that out. In the rare event however where a user perhaps types a space before `admin`, it will still fail. You can therefore use left and right `trim`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

print "Username: ";
my $user_name = <>;
$user_name =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

if ( $user_name eq 'admin' ) {
     print "Welcome, admin!\n";
}
else {
    print "The username is incorrect\n";
}
```

which will match `admin` followed by newline, space or tab before and space or tab after `admin`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to use `chomp`. When user has entered admin, it translated to `admin\n`, so we need to remove that `\n`. 
`chomp` is used to remove the `$/` variable (line feed character) which is set to mostly `\n` (new line). `$/` is the input record separator, newline by default.

```
use utf8;

print "Username: ";

$username = <STDIN>;
chomp $username;
if ( $username eq "admin" ) {
    print "Welcome, admin!";
}
else {
    print "The username is incorrect.";
}
```